# React ES6 Error: Invariant Violation: CampaignMobile.render()

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple example. I ma new to both react and ES6 so this is probably something stupid on my side:

*App.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CampaignListMobile } from './campaign_list_mobile.js'

var campaigns = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'My first testing'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'My second testing'
  }
];

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <CampaignListMobile campaigns={campaigns}/>
    );
  }
}
```

*campaign_list_mobile.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CampaignMobile } from './campaign_mobile.js'


export class CampaignListMobile extends Component {
  render() {
    let campaigns = [];
    let data = this.props.campaigns;
    data.forEach(function(campaign){
      var html = <li><CampaignMobile /></li>
      campaigns.push(html);
    }.bind(this));
    return (      
      <ul>
        {campaigns}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

*campaign_mobile.js:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class CampaignMobile extends Component {
  render() {
    <h2>Testing</h2>
  }
}
```

This throws an error

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: CampaignMobile.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

It is probably something to do with how I am trying to build the list inside of **CampaignListMobile**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the JSX (at the moment your render function is just returning undefined, i.e not a valid ReactComponent):

```
render() {
 return <h2>Testing</h2>;
}
```

Note that if it spans multiple lines you need to wrap it in `()`.

P.S. you probably don't need to include the `.js` extension in your imports

Also you might find using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and es6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) cleaner in a situation like this:

```
render() {
  return (      
    <ul>
      {this.props.campaigns.map(campaign => {
        return <li><CampaignMobile campaign={campaign} /></li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

And React will complain if you don't provide a unique `key` prop for each `li` as it can't efficiently update the list, so if `campaign` has some unique property then use that ie. `key={campaign.id}`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any good source for finding out more info about es6 with react? Maybe some nice links with tips and conventions?

Comment: @Kocur4d Hm not sure, I pick things up from random source code I read (as well as knowing about es6/7 stuff), once you have the basic stuff there aren't that many tricks - arrow functions, map that's a lot of what you'll use with rendering loops. Also you can use es7's `static` property for things like `propTypes` see: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers